# Why does this regex run differently in sed than in Perl/Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, perl, sed

I have a regex that gives me one result in `sed` but another in Perl (and Ruby).

I have the string `one;two;;three` and I want to highlight the substrings delimited by the `;`. So I do the following in Perl:

```
$a = "one;two;;three";
$a =~ s/([^;]*)/[\1]/g;
print $a;
```

(Or, in Ruby: `print "one;two;;three".gsub(/([^;]*)/, "[\\1]")`.)

The result is:

```
[one][];[two][];[];[three][]
```

(I know the reason for the spurious empty substrings.)

Curiously, when I run the same regexp in `sed` I get a different result. I run:

```
echo "one;two;;three" | sed -e 's/[^;]*/[\0]/g'
```

and I get:

```
[one];[two];[];[three]
```

What is the reason for this different result?

EDIT:

Somebody replied "because `sed` is not `perl`". I know that. The reason I'm asking my question is because I don't understand how `sed` copes so well with zero-length matches.

Comment: `sed` doesn't *"cope ... well with zero-length matches"* - it gets it wrong in a way that happens to do what you need. Write `join ';', map "[$_]", split /;/, $str` instead and don't use `a` as an identifier.

Comment: I cannot answer the question due to my  lack of knowledge about perl& ruby. however this is a good question. just was asked not in a right way... **+1** anyway... wait to learn how did perl/ruby handle the `greedy` matching.

Comment: @mirabilos: thanks; I was already aware of a way to get rid of the empty substrings. It wasn't the thing that bothered me.

Comment: @Kent: Yeah. I have a feeling that any mention of "Perl" in a question renders it to be "asked not in a right way". I had a feeling I should have dropped that word so that the more open-minded people would read it ;-)

Comment: I'm kind of surprised with the Perl/Ruby results. If the current location is just before the semicolon, and a zero-length string matches, why don't we get an infinite number of empty brackets?

Comment: This perl RE replicates the sed result: `s/(?:^|;)\K(.*?)(?=;|$)/[$1]/g`

Comment: @NiccoloM. Are you saying that people who read the Perl tag are not open-minded? What a completely unfair and unjustified thing to say.

Comment: @TLP:  I read it more as "people who _don't_ normally use perl, but see something tagged with `[perl]` may pre-judge the content solely based on the tag."

Comment: @mirabilos: `$a` and `$b` are used by perl for sorting: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html It's just good perl practice to avoid using them in other contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source code for `sed-4.2` for the substitute function:

```
   /sed/execute.c
  /* If we're counting up to the Nth match, are we there yet?
     And even if we are there, there is another case we have to
 skip: are we matching an empty string immediately following
     another match?

     This latter case avoids that baaaac, when passed through
     s,a*,x,g, gives `xbxxcx' instead of xbxcx.  This behavior is
     unacceptable because it is not consistently applied (for
     example, `baaaa' gives `xbx', not `xbxx'). */
```

This indicates that the behavior we see in Ruby and Perl was consciously avoided in `sed`. This is not due to any fundamental difference between the languages but a result of special handling in `sed`

Comment: Thank you. That's an exact answer. The article [Zero-Length Regex Matches](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html) explains the three ways to cope with zero-Length matches. The third way is to "skip zero-length matches at the position where the previous match ended, so you can never have a zero-length match immediately adjacent to a non-zero-length match," which you've just proved is what `sed` does.

Comment: sed is not alone. I tested python even vim's regex. all gave same result as sed's.

Comment: [`re` in Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) now handles zero-length matches like Perl: *Changed in version 3.7: Empty matches for the pattern are replaced when adjacent to a previous non-empty match.*

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting and surprising edge case.

Your `[^;]*` pattern *may* match the empty string, so it becomes a philosophy question, *viz.*, how many empty strings are between two characters: zero, one, or many?

### sed

The `sed` match clearly follows the philosophy described in the “Advancing After a Zero–Length Regex Match” section of [“Zero–Length Regex Matches.”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html)

> Now the regex engine is in a tricky situation. We’re asking it to go through the entire string to find all non–overlapping regex matches. The first match ended at the start of the string, where the first match attempt began. The regex engine needs a way to avoid getting stuck in an infinite loop that forever finds the same zero-length match at the start of the string.
>
> The simplest solution, which is used by most regex engines, is to start the next match attempt one character after the end of the previous match, if the previous match was zero–length.

That is, zero empty strings are between characters.

The above passage is not an authoritative standard, and quoting such a document instead would make this a better answer.

Inspecting the [source of GNU `sed`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/tree/sed/execute.c?id=8b65e07904384b529a464c89f3739d2e7e4d5135#n1135), we see

> ```
> /* Start after the match.  last_end is the real end of the matched
>    substring, excluding characters that were skipped in case the RE
>    matched the empty string.  */
> start = offset + matched;
> last_end = regs.end[0];
> ```

### Perl and Ruby

Perl’s philosophy with `s///`, which Ruby seems to share—so the documentation and examples below use Perl to represent both—is there is exactly one empty string after each character.

The [“Regexp Quote–Like Operators” section of the perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) documentation reads

> The `/g` modifier specifies global pattern matching—that is, matching as many times as possible within the string.

Tracing execution of `s/([^;]*)/[\1]/g` gives

1. Start. The “match position,” denoted by `^`, is at the beginning of the target string.

   ```
    o n e ; t w o ; ; t h r e e
   ^
   ```
2. Attempt to match `[^;]*`.

   ```
    o n e ; t w o ; ; t h r e e
         ^
   ```

   Note that the result captured in `$1` is `one`.
3. Attempt to match `[^;]*`.

   ```
    o n e ; t w o ; ; t h r e e
         ^
   ```

   **Important Lesson:** The `*` regex quantifier *always* succeeds because it means “zero or more.” In this case, the substring in `$1` is the empty string.

The rest of the match proceeds as in the above.

Being a perceptive reader, you now ask yourself, “Self, if `*` always succeeds, how does the match terminate at the end of the target string, or for that matter, how does it get past even the first zero–length match?”

We find the answer to this incisive question in the [“Repeated Patterns Matching a Zero–length Substring” section of the perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Repeated-Patterns-Matching-a-Zero-length-Substring) documentation.

> However, long experience has shown that many programming tasks may be significantly simplified by using repeated subexpressions that may match zero–length substrings. Here’s a simple example being:
>
> ```
> @chars = split //, $string; # // is not magic in split
> ($whitewashed = $string) =~ s/()/ /g; # parens avoid magic s// /
> ```
>
> Thus Perl allows such constructs, by forcefully breaking the infinite loop. The rules for this are different for lower–level loops given by the greedy quantifiers `*+{}`, and for higher-level ones like the `/g` modifier or `split` operator.
>
> …
>
> The higher–level loops preserve an additional state between iterations: whether the last match was zero–length. To break the loop, the following match after a zero–length match is prohibited to have a length of zero. This prohibition interacts with backtracking … and so the second best match is chosen if the best match is of zero length.

#### Other Perl approaches

With the addition of a negative lookbehind assertion, you can filter the spurious empty matches.

```
  $ perl -le '$a = "one;two;;three";
              $a =~ s/(?<![^;])([^;]*)/[\1]/g;
              print $a;'
  [one];[two];[];[three]
```

Apply what Mark Dominus dubbed [Randal’s Rule](http://perl.plover.com/flagbook/yak/Chi/slide066.html), “Use capturing when you know what you want to keep. Use `split` when you know what you want to throw away.” You want to throw away the semicolons, so your code becomes more direct with

```
$ perl -le '$a = "one;two;;three";
            $a = join ";", map "[$_]", split /;/, $a;
            print $a;'
[one];[two];[];[three]
```

Comment: I just edited your answer to include the section about higher-level loops (`/g` and `split`) instead of lower-level loops (`*+{}`), but now I'm not sure if that was appropriate since both types are in play here. Feel free to rollback.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yours is the better choice. Thanks for improving the answer. See update.

Comment: Thank you for the investigative work! The article you linked to is invaluable: it helped me understand things. But I have to award the Best Answer to @tihom because he pinpointed the reason. (BTW, reading that article I see that Ruby is different than Perl; They discuss matching `/\d*|x/` on `"x1"`. Ruby uses "[T]he simplest solution" whereas Perl uses "[T]he other solution".)

Comment: Item 3 `Attempt to match [^;]*.` makes no sense. You can't have an RE that matches "everything except a ;" and then have something in between "everything before the ;" and ";". Any perceived null string before the `;` is part of the string that matches `everything before the ;`. The RE `[^;]*` matches "zero or more characters that are not ;` it doesn't mean `zero or more character that are neither ; nor the null string`.

Comment: @EdMorton Perhaps it doesn't make sense, but that's exactly what Perl does. Run `perl -Mre=debug -e '$_ = "one;two;;three"; s/([^;]*)/[$1]/g'` to see for yourself. Although it's a slightly different case, ikegami gives a nice explanation for how this works with zero-length lookarounds [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=626295).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I believe that's what it does, it just makes no sense to do that. Oh well... at least sed and awk behave sanely.

Answer (score 0):

There's something else going on in the perl (and presumably ruby) scripts as that output makes no sense for simply handling the regexp as a BRE or ERE.

awk (EREs) and sed (BREs) behave as they should for just doing an RE replacement:

```
$ echo "one;two;;three" | sed -e 's/[^;]*/[&]/g'
[one];[two];[];[three]

$ echo "one;two;;three" | awk 'gsub(/[^;]*/,"[&]")'
[one];[two];[];[three]
```

You said `I know the reason for the spurious empty substrings.`. Care to clue us in?

Comment: As for "the reason for the the spurious empty substrings": Run `echo aaaa | sed -e 's/q*/[&]/'` to see a simple case. These are "zero-length matches" (see 1st link at answer by @Greg Bacon). Regular expressions have two basic rules: (1) match as early as possible, (2) match the longest run (unless we're non-greedy). `/q*/` (above) matches because it is the earliest match.

Comment: I understand zero length matches. I do not see any in the posted text and associated RE. `one` matches `[^;]*`. There is no additional zero-length match after it. If there were, there would ALWAYS be an infinite number of zero-length matches before and after every matching RE.